# Why are these two figures homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

In basically every introduction to Morse theory, we see the example of a height function on a torus. Morse theory then predicts that a torus minus a disk is homotopy equivalent to a cylinder with a 1-cell attached (see the figure below). I cannot see the homotopy equivalence. Can someone explain it to me?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both $S^1\vee S^1$. The figure on the right is homotopy equivalent to the one on the left by continuing to stretch the hole down until you just have a basket-handle formed by the top of the "donut hole."

Alternatively, you can form a torus by rolling up a sheet of paper and gluing the ends together. Either of these figures (as well as $S^1\vee S^1$) can be obtained by cutting out a window in the sheet of paper first.

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense!! Thank you so much!! Your first picture really enlightened it for me--I can basically turn a torus into a mug, and the removed dusk can be the bottom of the mug, and then now I have a mug body and handle, which is obviously homotopic to a cylinder with a 1-cell.

Comment: @Michael Not quite. Remember that the torus is just the *surface* of the mug, so if you remove the whole bottom, you're actually removing *two* disks, so I'm not sure the mug heuristic helps so much here.

Comment: Ah, you are right--I was mistaken. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand this answer. In what sense is it that both figures "are" $S^1 \vee S^1$? And while I understand that the usual identifications of opposite edges of a square gives, if you first remove a 2-disk inside that square, the torus minus a disk, how does removing such a 2-disk inside the square give, after identifying just one pair of opposite edges of the square, the cylinder with a 1-cell attached -- where does that attached 1-cell come from there?

Comment: @murray They're all homotopy equivalent to S¹∨S¹. If the hole in the square goes all the way to the edges of the square, the identification that would produce the torus instead produces S¹∨S¹. And if the hole is a rectangle that extends to only one pair of opposite edges, you get the basket-shape above.

Comment: In fact, isn't the cylinder with the 1-cell atttached a deformation retract of the torus with a hole? (Or am I missing something here?)

Comment: @murray Yes, I described the retract in my answer above.